# org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.DeprecationHandler Exception while using Elasticsearch REST High level client

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I am getting the following exception while trying to use Elasticsearch high rest client.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.4 and Elasticsearch 6.4 versions.. The use case is simply to create an index with some data and then retrieving the same..

```
2018-08-24 14:25:44.185 ERROR 18768 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/common/xcontent/DeprecationHandler] with root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.DeprecationHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.<clinit>(RestHighLevelClient.java:1429) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-6.4.0.jar:5.6.10]
    at com.softwareag.laasapi.rest.service.ElasticService.getClient(ElasticService.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.softwareag.laasapi.rest.service.ElasticService.getDocuments(ElasticService.java:57) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.softwareag.laasapi.rest.controller.LogsController.getDocuments(LogsController.java:52) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
```

I have just followed the elasticsearch documentation for [dependencies](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.4/java-rest-high-getting-started-maven.html) and set up correctly.

My Gradle dependency is

```
dependencies {
   compile 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:6.4.0'
}
```

For the sake of simplicity, given an short version of the code..

```
@RestController
public class ElasticController {

@RequestMapping("/posts")
public void getData() {

    RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
                RestClient.builder(
                        new HttpHost("localhost", "9200","http")));

    GetRequest request = new GetRequest("posts", "doc", "1");
    GetResponse response = client.get(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

    System.out.println(response.getSource().toString());

}
}
```

Could anyone help on this?

Comment: Please add relevant code, by looking into exception trace its not possible to exactly tell what's the issue. In your case you should add the build.gradle file and then the snippet you're using.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, I found the following [link](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/26959) useful  to nail down the issue..

As per elasticsearch [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.4/java-rest-high-getting-started-maven.html), it is only required to add "**elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client**" dependency.. However, I just observed it in Gradle build that it picks up the other dependency with lower version number; in my case it is 5.6.10

[image]

Right now, I just added the following dependency as well in my build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.elasticsearch', name: 'elasticsearch', version: '6.4.0'
    compile group: 'org.elasticsearch.client', name: 'elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client', version: '6.4.0'
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

That resolves it. I see the same problem being reported in other forums but hope this helps them.. (may be Elasticsearch documentation have to include this as well).

Comment: There is no need to include org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch.
Because when you include org.elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client, it will resolve peer dependencies.
The root cause of this exception is the version of es-client dependency and your Elasticsearch server version.
I have an ES server v6.2.0 while using es-rest-high-level-client:6.4.0 then it failed, so I fixed to 6.2.0 and it worked.
You can read the compability guide https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.4/java-rest-high-compatibility.html

Comment: Very good point made. I have one question. I have a ES server version 6.4.2 and rest-high-level-client version 6.4.2 but still I get this error. However when I use rest-high-level-client version 6.2.0 I am not getting this error. Do you know why

Comment: This saved me some headache while working on an older version of the ES client.

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered the same problem.

In my senario, The pom.xml of my project extends the `spring-boot-starter-parent`, and there is a maven property `elasticsearch.version` and `dependencyManagement` about elasticsearch defined in the `spring-boot-dependencies`, which is the parent of `spring-boot-starter-parent`.

Because of that,the actual version of elasticsearch artifact depended by `elasticsearch-client` may be not the same as the version you specify to `elasticsearch-client`. Then you got a ClassNotFoudException due to the mismatch version between `elasticsearch-client` and the elasticsearch artifact it depend on.

```xml
<elasticsearch.version>5.6.8</elasticsearch.version>
```

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuGa4.png)

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
                <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
                <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
                <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
                <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.elasticsearch.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>transport-netty4-client</artifactId>
                <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
            </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0o2J.png)

To solve this,you can simply define `elasticsearch.version` property in your  `pom.xml` to overwrite the one in the `parent pom.xml`

```xml
<elasticsearch.version>The version you want</elasticsearch.version>
```

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this problem. Basically the root cause of this exception is version mismatch for Elastic-Search Lib, elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client and ElasticSearch Server . 
**I am using ElasticSearch Server 7.4 and Apache Flink 1.10.** I have added following dependency in POM for Flink-Elastic-Search Sink:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-elasticsearch7_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>

        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

This is working perfectly for me.

**Note: Elastic-Search Server version and dependency version of elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client version, and Elastic-Search , SINK connector should be exactly same to avoid this issue.**

Comment: adding both jar of <version>7.4.0</version> , resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. At last I found I have to provide the `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch` dependency and keep the version same with my rest-high-level-client.

If I don't do that, it will default to `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:5.6.10`, but I am using rest-client 6.4.x